# Can a Windows Service monitor and restart a desktop user application?

Tags: windows, session, service, monitoring, desktop-application

Is it possible to use a Windows Service to make sure a certain application is always running on the desktop of the logged-in user?

I'm pretty sure because of session isolation I can't do that, but what I'm trying to accomplish is making sure a certain process (running on the desktop) is always running and I'd also like to be able to kill it, update it, and restart it if needed.